# Handlers, Threads and View manipulation

Tags: android, android-handler

I am trying to manipulate a TextView from my Fragment's `onResume()` method. I have defined a Handler and attempt to change the text from within `run()` after calling the Handler's `post()`. While this does change the TextView's text, I try manipulating the same TextView outside the Handler,however the TextView's text does not change. What is happening in this situation and why doesn't the TextView change to "BAR". All the code I executed is right below:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    mHandler = new Handler();
    Looper looper = mHandler.getLooper();
    Thread thread = looper.getThread();
    Log.v("THREAD",thread.getName());
    // prints main in logcat

    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                // TextView's text changes to "FOO"
                mTextView.setText("FOO");
            }
            catch(Exception exception){

                exception.toString();
            }
        }
    });

    // Logcat prints this message  
    Log.v("AFTER HANDLER","AFTER HANDLER");
    // TextView's text does not change to "BAR"
    mTextView.setText("BAR");
}
```

Apologies if I have missed something elementary, but any clarification on this would be very helpful. Thanks !

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Handler.post()` is intended for when you'd like to perform a UI operation from outside the UI thread. When it does is add the runnable you pass to the method, and queue it so that on the next UI pass, your runnable will run.

`onResume()` is called on the UI thread anyway, so queuing this operation on the UI thread isn't necessary. The way it will work doesn't change tho - on the next UI pass (not the current pass, the *next* one), the `TextView's` text will change to "FOO".

On the current pass of the UI thread in the onResume method, you're also setting the text to "BAR". For a split second, the `TextView` really displays this text. However, on the next UI pass which occurs very shortly afterwards, the "BAR" text is replaced with "FOO".

This is why you don't see the "FOO" text. You're scheduling another UI pass immediately afterwards and text is replaced before you can even notice it was something different.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I tried getting the TextView's text and printing to Logcat does show "BAR".

Answer (score 1):

`Handler.post(Runnable r)` causes `r` to be added to message queue. It does not run immediately. In your case "BAR" is set first and after that "FOO" is set.

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that `mTextView.setText("BAR")` is the first and `mTextView.setText("FOO")` is the second.

What is happen if the code is below?

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    mHandler = new Handler();
    Looper looper = mHandler.getLooper();
    Thread thread = looper.getThread();
    Log.v("THREAD",thread.getName());
    // prints main in logcat

    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.v("Which is earlier?", "FOO");
                mTextView.setText("FOO");
            }
            catch(Exception exception){

                exception.toString();
            }
        }
    });

    Log.v("Which is earlier?", "BAR");
    mTextView.setText("BAR");
}
```